# how to use different database with same table structure in typed dataset xsd

Tags: xsd, dataset, strongly-typed-dataset, typed-dataset

I'm confused how to explain myself well here is my scenario.
I have a database named "database1" and i have used typed dataset in visual studio and have added more than 200 stored procedures in the table adapters.
it is a desktop based application. now i want to deployee the same software in other school same database but i have changed the database name
when i generate new database from query and write all the stored procedures in the database and change the database name in the connection string it doesn't work.

Comment: Afraid we need more detail than 'doesn't work'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you don't change the database name, or if it's something specific to the first client (like ParisTechnicalCollegeDatabase), change it now to something generic (SchoolManager) so you never have to change it again. There's no specific problem I can think of regards reusing a typed dataSet on a different database: I do it daily on database that aren't clones of each other. Ensure your second server is set up with a user and default schema that is specified in the connection string. The problem will eithe per be faulty connection string or incorrect database setup, not the fault of the dataSet

For more targeted help, post up the error messages that appear when you try to run your app on the new database